# Why does using IEnumerable<T> inside a recursive method make it much slower than using a List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I am using a recursive method to go through a tree of items and add its children to a flat collection:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var sampleData = new List<Thing>
    {
        new Thing { Id = 1,  Name = "root1", ParentId = null },
        new Thing { Id = 2,  Name = "2", ParentId = 1 },
        new Thing { Id = 3,  Name = "3", ParentId = 1 },
        new Thing { Id = 4,  Name = "4", ParentId = 2 },
        new Thing { Id = 5,  Name = "5", ParentId = 2 },
        new Thing { Id = 6,  Name = "6", ParentId = 2 },
        new Thing { Id = 7,  Name = "7", ParentId = 6 },
        new Thing { Id = 8,  Name = "8", ParentId = 7 },
        new Thing { Id = 9,  Name = "9", ParentId = 8 },
        new Thing { Id = 10,  Name = "10", ParentId = 9 },
        new Thing { Id = 11,  Name = "11", ParentId = 10 },
        new Thing { Id = 12,  Name = "12", ParentId = 11 },
        new Thing { Id = 13,  Name = "13", ParentId = 12 },
        new Thing { Id = 14,  Name = "14", ParentId = 13 },
        new Thing { Id = 15,  Name = "root15", ParentId = null }
    };

    var subThings = new HashSet<Thing>();
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    //AddSubThings(subThings, sampleData, new List<int> { 1 });
    AddSubThingsUsingList(subThings, sampleData, new List<int> { 1 });
    stopWatch.Elapsed.Dump();
    subThings.Dump();
}

private void AddSubThings(HashSet<Thing> resultThings, IEnumerable<Thing> sourceThings, IEnumerable<int> parentIds)
{
    if (!sourceThings.Any() || !parentIds.Any())
    {
        return;
    }
    var subThings = sourceThings.Where(st => st.ParentId.HasValue && parentIds.Contains(st.ParentId.Value));
    resultThings.UnionWith(subThings);
    AddSubThings(resultThings, sourceThings.Except(subThings), subThings.Select(st => st.Id));
}

private void AddSubThingsUsingList(HashSet<Thing> resultThings, List<Thing> sourceThings, List<int> parentIds)
{
    if (!sourceThings.Any() || !parentIds.Any())
    {
        return;
    }
    var subThings = sourceThings.Where(st => st.ParentId.HasValue && parentIds.Contains(st.ParentId.Value));
    resultThings.UnionWith(subThings);
    AddSubThingsUsingList(resultThings, sourceThings.Except(subThings).ToList(), subThings.Select(st => st.Id).ToList());
}
```

When I use the `AddSubThings` method it takes around 90 seconds to process. However if I use the `AddSubThingsUsingList` method it does not even take a second. Why is this?

Comment: Since people are deleting their answers left and right - try adding ref to addsubthings (change ienumerable<thing> to ref ienumerable<thing>). I'm curious if it's getting passed by value.

Comment: @Charles And what makes you think that will help?

Comment: @Charles They are reference types, so it doesn't matter if they are pass by reference.  Passing by reference is only needed if you reassign a passed in variable, and you want the change to be reflected in the calling variable, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because your create `subThings` from `sourceThings` like this

```
var subThings = sourceThings.Where(
    st => st.ParentId.HasValue && parentIds.Contains(st.ParentId.Value));
```

Then you pass the following as `sourceThings` to the recursive call.

```
sourceThings.Except(subThings)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
sourceThings.Except(
    sourceThings.Where(
        st => st.ParentId.HasValue && parentIds.Contains(st.ParentId.Value)))
```

That query when iterated with have to iterate over the original list twice.  With each recursive call the query will build up and need to iterate the original list 2^n times where n is the recursion level.  And your query is being iterated by the `Any` and the `HashSet.UnionWith` calls meaning it's more like 2^(n+1).

The other one immediately iterates the query before passing them and thus avoids this doubling problem.

You could pass the following to your recursive call for `sourceThings` instead to make it faster as it doesn't double up the required iterating of the original list on each recursive call.

```
sourceThings.Where(st => !st.ParentId.HasValue || !parentIds.Contains(st.ParentId.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is a bit complex.

Operations on IEnumerable are lazy, i.e. they are not executed until you need the result. Now when you pass `sourceThins` and `subThings` to `AddSubThings`, you've not sent a materialized collection of things, all you've done is you've defined how these collections are calculated from the original `List`s.

Now when the method calls itself recursively, it adds more filtering and selection to the data it has received.

All these layers of selection and filtering will be called when you call `Any()`.

On the other hand, in the case of `List`s, things are materialized after calls to `Where`, `Except` and `Select`, because you call `ToList`.

Comment: recursive filtering and selecting isn't the problem.  It's specifically the `Except` that ultimately iterates the same sequence twice and that's the sequence that will get iterated twice on the next recursive call.  Also things are not materialized for `Where` and `Except` and `Select` when called on a `List`.  They are materialized because of the `ToList` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I corrected my last paragraph

Comment: Also, your inspection of the code is much better, while the recursive filtering can turn an O(n) code into O(n^2), the problem here is much more serious, because of `Except()`, as you've explained.